# How to count number of circular pipes in an image using Deep Learning or Machine Learning?

Tags: deep-learning

I'm trying to build a program to count the number of pipes from a given image, here are some example test images.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

I want to use deep learning for the same. I have looked at several blogs and research papers but find it difficult to create my own CNN for the same, as I have just started studying Neural Networks.

Can I use YOLO for object detection or UNet for segmentation?
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7KFi.jpg
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yoc2.jpg

Comment: Your images are not showing up. Please edit your post.